# Bash Xargs Sleep (Multiple Command Line Arguments)

Tags: bash, sleep, xargs

Ok so I have the following script that updates Route43 DNS entries. Unfortunately there is a limit to the number of calls per second you can make so I need to make the final Xargs command sleep for about a second between each iteration.

I've tried a couple of things like ' {../cli53 blah; sleep 10; } ' and I cant seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any suggestions please:

```
#!/bin/bash

set root='dirname $0'
ec2-describe-instances -O ******* -W ******* --region eu-west-1 |
perl -ne '/^INSTANCE\s+(i-\S+).*?(\S+\.amazonaws\.com)/
and do { $dns = $2; print "$1 $dns\n" }; /^TAG.+\sName\s+(\S+)/
and print "$1 $dns\n"' |
perl -ane 'print "$F[0] CNAME $F[1] --replace\n"' |
grep -v 'i-' | xargs --verbose -n 4 /usr/local/bin/cli53 rrcreate -x 5 contoso.com
```

---

Edit: Thanks Etan for the Answer. Here is my solution for anyone else that needs it:

I had to include the -I %variable% switch into the xargs statement aswel to make sure that the feed in was passed as parameters to cli53 but it all looks to be working nicely now.

```
#!/bin/bash

set root='dirname $0'
ec2-describe-instances -O ******* -W ******* --region eu-west-1 |
perl -ne '/^INSTANCE\s+(i-\S+).*?(\S+\.amazonaws\.com)/
and do { $dns = $2; print "$1 $dns\n" }; /^TAG.+\sName\s+(\S+)/
and print "$1 $dns\n"' |
perl -ane 'print "$F[0] CNAME $F[1] --replace\n"' |
grep -v '^i-' |
xargs --verbose -n 4 -I myvar /bin/sh -c '{ /usr/local/bin/cli53 rrcreate -x 5 contoso.com 'myvar'; sleep 1; printf "\n\n"; }'
```

Comment: Those "inner" single quotes don't work the way you expect them to. They are ending and starting outer single quoted strings leaving `myvar` unquoted. They **are not** single quoting the `myvar` expansion inside the outer single quoted string. Use double quotes around `myvar` instead. Or, alternatively, use the script's positional arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to simply put the `cli53` and `sleep` calls in a script and use `xargs` to execute the script.

If you don't want to do that you should be able to do what you were trying to do with this:

```
... | xargs ... /bin/sh -c '{ /usr/local/bin/cli53 ... "$@"; sleep 10; }' -
```

Comment: I'd like to use the latter however when I put the {cli53 ; sleep 10;} command in it wont work. Would you give me an example of exactly how I should integrate the sleep into the xargs line please?

Edit: O I think I've been missing out the "/bin/sh -c" - I wont be able to test until the morning now.

Comment: Yes, you need the `/bin/bash -c` part because `xargs` only executes a single command. In this case you get it to execute a single invocation of `/bin/sh` (or `/bin/bash` if you needed it) and that invocation happens to contain a shell script as an argument.

Comment: See my comment on the OP for why your solution isn't quite correct and my edit here for a more correct way to do it.